# GroupLayout makes action listener loses focus

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, keylistener, grouplayout

I've recently started to work with the java GUI -most properly Swing.

Now I got this problem I just can't get around.
I want to dispose a game board that extends `JPanel` and implements `ActionListener` (something) like this:

```
+----------------+
| Panel1 | Board |
|________|       |
| Panel2 |       |
|        |       |
+----------------+
```

But I'm getting this:

```
+----------------+
| Panel1 | Board |
|________|_______|
| Panel2 | EMPTY |
|        |       |
+----------------+
```

I started by trying to do this using the `GridLayout` for the main pane with `BoxLayout`ed panels inside but that didn't work. Then I found `GroupLayout`, wich lead me to the above case and made me lost control/focus of my listener inside the board class.

[EDIT] I also tried to change the minimun and prefered sizes of board, didn't worked either.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Resuming:

1. Why is the group layout doing this to the Board panel? Anyway I can fix it?
2. Since inside the Board class I do setFocusable(true); why can't it get actions/events after being inside the group layout?(Works fine without it)

Here's the code:

Game class

```
...
public ConstructorOfTheClassThatExtendsJFrame() {

        statusbar = new JLabel(" 0");
        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        Board board = new Board(this);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        //Specify automatic gap insertion:
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        //PANEL 1
        col1 = new JPanel();
        col1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        //PANEL 3
        col3 = new JPanel();
        col3.add(statusbar);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
              layout.createSequentialGroup()
                              .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(col1)
                    .addComponent(col3))
                .addComponent(board)
              );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
              layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(col1)
                    .addComponent(board))
                .addComponent(col3)
              );



        setSize(400, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("GameOn");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
```

and my Board class (from [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/tetris/))

```
public Board(Game parent) {

        setFocusable(true);  
        curPiece = new Shape();
        timer = new Timer(400, this);
        timer.start(); 

        statusbar =  parent.getStatusBar();
        board = new Tetrominoes[BoardWidth * BoardHeight];
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        clearBoard();  
     }
...
class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if (!isStarted || curPiece.getShape() == Tetrominoes.NoShape) {  
                return;
            }

            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

            if (keycode == 'p' || keycode == 'P') {
                pause();
                return;
            }

            if (isPaused)
                return;

            switch (keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                tryMove(curPiece, curX - 1, curY);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                tryMove(curPiece, curX + 1, curY);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                //tryMove(curPiece, curX, curY - 1);
                oneLineDown();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                tryMove(curPiece.rotateRight(), curX, curY);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                dropDown();
                break;
            case 'd':
                oneLineDown();
                break;
            case 'D':
                oneLineDown();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT:
                newPiece();
                break;
            }

        }
```

---

[EDIT] After some advice, here's a sscce version of the code where the key events work but the alignment is still wrong:

**The game class(this case is hello world but still)**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

public class HelloWorldSwing{

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        //Create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        //Create the new group layout
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        //We specify automatic gap insertion:
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);


        //PANEL 1
        JPanel col1 = new JPanel();
        col1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        //PANEL 2
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Col2");
        Board board = new Board(label2, new BorderLayout());

        //PANEL 3
        JPanel col3 = new JPanel();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Col1");

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Col3");

        col1.add(label);
        board.add(label2,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        col3.add(label3);


        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                   layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                           .addComponent(col1)
                           .addComponent(col3))
                      .addComponent(board)
                );
                layout.setVerticalGroup(
                   layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                           .addComponent(col1)
                           .addComponent(board))
                      .addComponent(col3)
                );

        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**And the board class:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JLabel blabel;
    public Board(JLabel label, BorderLayout b) {
        super(b);
        setFocusable(true);
        blabel = label;
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
     }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }


    class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

            switch (keycode) {

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                blabel.setText("Left");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                blabel.setText("Right");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                blabel.setText("Down");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). It makes me suspicious though when I see JPanels that require focus. Why is this necessary? And why have the GUI class implement the listener interface? Usually your code is easier to maintain if these are kept separate.

Comment: And a layout should not effect ActionListener events, so I have to wonder if something else is different or wrong. It's hard for me to tell based on the information that you've presented so far which is why the [sscce](http://sscce.org) would help *immensely*.

Comment: About sscce, I don't think I can minimize it more than I did. The text is fuzzy, but that is because of my english, I can't express myself shorter(I think). Anyway, if you still think it is too big and not 'concise' tell me and I'll try my best. 
About the GUI implementing listener, this is a fast tetris that I'm programming. No MVC or Command-Kernel pattern, 'hard code', I guess.

Comment: Ok, I'm already trying to minimize my board so I can put it here. In a minute.

Comment: I can't compile and run any of your code, I can't reproduce your problem with it, so unfortunately, I can't help. Maybe someone else will be able to figure this out, but without more info and best of all short compilable code, I'm up against a wall I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, it needs to be 'compilable', sorry. New edit coming.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I'm not being able to send you a version compilable without sending the all code. At least not for now. It still takes me some time to write code using GUI, sorry. 
I'll keep working on it.

Comment: It's not easy isolating the problem in this way, but I still recommend that you try to do this, even if you never post the code here, because often the effort will allow you to see the problem and its solution yourself. Good luck!

Comment: I know, I really am trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one thing in your code that could be a problem and that may be fixed without too much difficulty: you're using KeyListeners. This should in general be avoided in Swing GUI's and instead you should try to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which are more flexible and which do not require that the bound component have focus.

Regarding your GroupLayout sizing issue,  I have to admit to being very weak on use of GroupLayout, and in fact I try to avoid its use assiduously. Other layouts to consider include GridBagLayout or the MigLayout.

**Edit:**
However, I have now read the GroupLayout tutorial, including [section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) labeled "To force a component to be resizable (allow shrinking and growing):". It appears that you must add some parameters when you add your component to the layout which in my code example looks like:

```
.addComponent(board2, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
```

For instance, here's my code showing components laid out as desired, and also showing use of KeyBindings and a PropertyChangeListener. Notice that by using Key Bindings, focus is no longer as big of an issue as I don't have to set the JPanel to be focusable nor to give it the focus:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * uses GroupLayout and Key Bindings
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784773/grouplayout-makes-action-listener-loses-focus
 * @author Pete
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloWorldSwing2GroupLayout extends JPanel {
   private JLabel[] labels = {new JLabel("A"), new JLabel("B")};
   private Board2 board2 = new Board2();
   private JLabel directionLabel = new JLabel();

   public HelloWorldSwing2GroupLayout() {
      directionLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      board2.add(directionLabel);

      board2.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (Board2.DIRECTION.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               Direction dir = (Direction)pcEvt.getNewValue();
               if (dir != null) {
                  directionLabel.setText(dir.getText());
               } else {
                  directionLabel.setText("");
               }
            }
         }
      });

      GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
      setLayout(layout);

      int lWidth = board2.getPreferredSize().width;
      int lHeight = board2.getPreferredSize().height / 2;
      Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(lWidth, lHeight);
      for (JLabel label : labels) {
         label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
         label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
         label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

         // please, please forgive me Jeanette! This is for demo purposes only.
         label.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
      }

      layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
      layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                  .addComponent(labels[0], 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                  .addComponent(labels[1], 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(board2, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addComponent(labels[0], 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                  .addComponent(labels[1], 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(board2, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)      
      );
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      HelloWorldSwing2GroupLayout mainPanel = new HelloWorldSwing2GroupLayout();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Board2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 200;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   public static final String DIRECTION = "direction";
   private Direction direction = null;

   public Board2() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Board2"));
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

      for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
         inputMap.put(dir.getKeyStroke(), dir.getText());
         actionMap.put(dir.getText(), new MyArrowBinding(dir));
      }
   }

   private class MyArrowBinding extends AbstractAction {
      private Direction dir;

      public MyArrowBinding(Direction dir) {
         super(dir.getText());
         this.dir = dir;
         putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, dir);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         setDirection(dir);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public void setDirection(Direction direction) {
      Direction oldValue = this.direction;
      Direction newValue = direction;
      this.direction = newValue;

      firePropertyChange(DIRECTION, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public Direction getDirection() {
      return direction;
   }
}

enum Direction {
   UP("Up", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0)),
   DOWN("Down", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0)),
   LEFT("Left", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0)),
   RIGHT("Right", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0));

   Direction(String text, KeyStroke keyStroke) {
      this.text = text;
      this.keyStroke = keyStroke;
   }
   private String text;
   private KeyStroke keyStroke;

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public KeyStroke getKeyStroke() {
      return keyStroke;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return text;
   }
}
```

Which will look like so:
[image]

I'm a big fan of using PropertyChangeListeners for this sort of thing since it allows for easy decoupling of your code. Now the Board2 class doesn't have to worry about how other classes react to any changes in its direction. All it must do is broadcast this change to any classes that happening to be listening to it, and they each respond as they see fit.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know those, I'll study/implement them. 
About the position, do you have any idea? Cause that part has nothing to do with the focus/events, is layout'ing'.

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto: I have to admit to being very weak on use of GroupLayout, and in fact I try to avoid its use assiduously. Other layouts to consider include GridBagLayout or the MigLayout.

Comment: ,it's ok, I'll find it eventually, or maybe somebody will help with this one. I got my sscce code almost ready (I'm actually using one of your answers to make it simpler)
Hope then it will make thing easier.

Comment: I made a new edit to the question with short compilable code. Hope that helps people helping me :)

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto: what is the desired behavior of your sscce?

Comment: Like I said in he question, I want the Board panel to have the total height of the Frame, not to be divided like col1 and col 3 panels.
I think the draw that I made in the question can help you understand. 
And, once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto: OK, I studied GroupLayout and think I know what your problem is. Please see the edit to my answer for this and more on key bindings.